# Creating (mocked) Repository for Unit Testing - what to use instead of DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

I have to create Unit testing infrastructure in the project. However, I am a bit stuck on **how to mock Repository** and which structure to use instead of `DbContext`.

Here is our **Repository**:

```
 public class Repository : IRepository
    {
        protected readonly IProjContext _context;    
        public Repository(IProjContext context)
        {
            this._context = context;
        }    

    public T GetById<T>(object id) where T : class
        {
            return _context.Set<T>().Find(id);       
        }
   ...}
```

**Interface for IRepository**

```
 public interface IRepository {
        T GetById<T>(object id) where T : class;
        ... }
```

**DB Context**

```
public class ProjContext : DbContext, IProjContext { ... }
```

**DB Context Interface**

```
public interface IProjContext : IDbContext { ... }
```

There are a lot of similar methods in this class (that also implements interface `IRepository`) - `Count`, `Delete`, etc. and also `SaveChanges`.

As you see, we use single Repository without UnitOfWork. Now I have to mock it.

I decided not to use any Mocking framework and just created our own `MockedRepository`. It should be something like this:

```
public class MockedRepository: IRepository
{
    public T GetById<T>(object id) where T : class {
            /// ??????   Get data from where?
   }    
}
```

The question is - as `MockedRepository` is used for Unit Testing, I do not need DbContext there. However, I cannot understand which structure to use instead of DbContext to be able to add data (generic data that means data of different types `T`) to repository and to implement simple method slike `GetById<T>` and others.

Comment: Any collection can be used as a backing store for the mock. like an array or List.

Comment: I understand this. But I have different classes like Users, Payments etc. and my Repository doesn't have "T" (it is not generic itself, generic are methods). So where to defined all those lists? And how to retrieve appropriate list when calling for instance GetById?

Comment: It is difficult to describe "what is the problem I do not use Lists", can you plese give me a small example with MockedRepository that could work with two classes - Users and Payments for instance (taking into account that I have much more different classes).